# What is the definition of "convergence in total variation"?

Tags: probability

I've been asked to show that the Poisson distribution with parameter $1/n$ converges in total variation distance to the Dirac distribution at zero. The only problem is, I don't know what that means, and I can't find a single clear definition anywhere; not online, not in the textbook, not in the notes. I've found a number of discussion about convergence in total variation on here, but none that clearly define what that means in the first place.

I have a somewhat intuitive sense of what this type of convergence means, but I need a definition to work from. If someone could be nice enough to give me the definition I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What do you not understand about the definition [given on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Total_variation_convergence_of_measures)? Total variation defines a distance between measures, and you want to show that this distance goes to zero in your example.

Comment: I was mostly just confused because on Wikipedia it's called "Total Variance Convergence of Measures", so I wasn't sure if that was even the same thing as "Converging in Total Variance". But if those are the same things then I can work with that definition. Thanks.